# $\sup_{n}\|A_n\|<+\infty$ using Banach - Steinhaus theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, inner-products

Let's consider $l^2$ with standard dot product and $A_n:l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ linear and continuous maps. Additionaly assume that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|<A_n(x), y>| < + \infty,\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \text{for}\; x,y \in l^2$$

I want to show that $\sup_{n}\|A_n\| < + \infty$ but there can be situation that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|A_n\| = + \infty$.

**My work so far**

Since $l^2$ is Banach space we can use Banach - Steinhaus theorem. So to show $\sup\|A_n\| < +\infty$ we jut want to show $\sup\|A_n(x)\|<+\infty$.

Rewriting sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|<A_n(x), y>|$ and using Cauchy Schwarz inequality:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|<A_n(x), y>| = |<A_1(x), y>| + |<A_2(x), y>| +....\le$$
$$\le \|A_1(x)\| \|y\| + \|A_2(x)\|\|y\| +... = \|y\| \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty\|A_n(x)\|$$

We know that $\|y\| \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty\|A_n(x)\| < + \infty$. Since $y \in l^2$ we have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|A_n(x)\| < +\infty$ . Finally:

$$ + \infty > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|A_n(x)\| \ge \sup\|A_n(x)\|$$

So now by using Banach Steinhaus theorem we have that $\sup\|A_n\| < +\infty$.

**Questions**

1. Is my justification that $\sup_{n}\|A_n\| < + \infty$ correct?
2. I tried to find some examples that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|A_n\| = + \infty$ but I couldn't find any good example. Could you please give me a hint how can I construct such a example?

Comment: Your proof is not correct. You proved that $\|y\| \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty\|A_n(x)\|$ is larger or equal to a finite number. Of course this does not mean that it is finite itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for the second part: Take $A_nx= \langle x, e_n \rangle e_n$. Then the hypothesis holds by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but $\|A_n\|=1$ for all $n$.

Hint for the first part: Apply Banach Steinhaus Theorem twice. Since $ \langle A_nx, y \rangle \to 0$ it follows that  $(\langle A_nx, y \rangle)$ is bounded for each $y$ and one application of the theorem shows that $\sup_n \|A_n x\| <\infty$ for each $x$. Another applicatin of the theorem finishes the proof.

Comment: How boundness of $(\langle A_nx, y \rangle)$ combined with application of Banach Steinhaus theorem implies $\sup_n\|A_nx\| < + \infty$? I cannot understand that.

Comment: Define $T_n (y)= \langle A_nx, y \rangle$ with $x$ fixed. Apply B-S theem to this sequence of (scalar valued) operators. Note that $\|T_n\|=\|A_nx\|$.  @Lucian